# Solve equation with fraction indices in sympy

Tags: python, scipy, sympy

I would like to solve below equation:

```
y**(-0.24) + y**(-0.16) + y**(-0.08) - 1.99957291987653
```

I am using sympy solve(y**(-0.24) + y**(-0.16) + y**(-0.08) - 1.99957291987653,y)
but this is getting stuck and hangs my laptop.

any way to resolve this in sympy or numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the equation using sympy nsolve:

```
nsolve(y**(-0.24) + y**(-0.16) + y**(-0.08) - 1.99957291987653,y,0.1)
```